# Color different in UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Following is the code to customize the `searchBar` embedded in the `navigationBar`. I set the same `tintColor` for both `navigationBar` and `searchBar`. Bur it seems there is some difference in tabbar's tint color and navigation bar tint color. What could be the problem?

[image]

```
- (void)viewdidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Change the navigation bar color
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:kAppNavigationItemGrayColor];

    //Create a UISearchBar
    UISearchBar *topBarSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    [topBarSearchBar setBarTintColor:kAppNavigationItemGrayColor];

    //Wrapper view to hold searchbar
    UIView *searchBarWrapper = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 310.0, 44.0)];
    [topBarSearchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 310.0, 44.0)];
    [searchBarWrapper setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [searchBarWrapper addSubview:self.topBarSearchBar];
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:searchBarWrapper];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

Comment: maybe your `navigationBar` have `translucent` on, try change it to false and see if they are same

Comment: Most likely: the search bar sits on top of the navigation bar, and the colour of both is translucent. This means that the colours add up where they overlap. Make the search bar colour completely transparent instead.

Comment: @fishinear, Do you mean UIClearColor? If so it becomes blackColor

Comment: @Tj3n I ll try that one

Comment: @jailani Then that is probably your problem: there is some black color behind it. Maybe you forget to set the `opaque` property of your `searchBarWrapper` to `NO`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `[searchBarWrapper setBackgroundColor: kAppNavigationItemGrayColor];`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set,

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```